# Facelets custom function not found

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I'm writing a simple custom function in Facelets with a sample method. The problem is that the JSF 2 application fails to locate that function. The error message is:

```
/test.xhtml @15,73 rendered="#{test:isGranted('ONE_ROLE')}" Function 'test:isGranted' not found.
```

I've been checking and rechecking and can't find the problem. Any comment here would be really appreciated as it's clear that I'm missing something (but it seems that the steps involved are really simple).

Do you know if there are other requisites?

Thanks in advance.

The relevant code:

In the **web.xml** the tag XML descriptor is declared

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The file **test.taglib.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.test.com/security/tags</namespace>
    <function>
        <function-name>isGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>com.test.security.taglibs.IsGranted</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isGranted(java.lang.String role)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

The tag class:

```
public class IsGranted extends TagHandler {
    public static boolean isGranted(String role) {
        // Do nothing. Just a test.
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the test file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/security/tags">

    <body>
        <h:outputText value="You should NOT see this." rendered="#{test:isGranted('ONE_ROLE')}"/>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are declaring the `sec` namespace prefix but use the `test` prefix in your function call. But maybe that was just a copying mistake.

Another possible cause would be the header of your taglib file, which uses the facelets 1.0 DTD instead of the JSF 2.0 version. This might be problematic depending on your JSF implementation, for example for MyFaces see [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-2543) and [discussion thread](http://marc.info/?t=126701802700002&r=1&w=4). The header for a JSF 2.0 taglib would be:

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
```