# ValueChangeListener on custom component leads to PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

We have a custom JSF component that renders some buttons and a select box in a specific way. This is done by a class that extends `UIInput`. This custom component used in the `xhtml` templates like so:

```
<xx:fooComponent
    value="#{fooBean.someProperty}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{fooBean.someMethodInBean}"
    someOtherProperties="true" />
```

Now since we changed from JBoss 4.2.2 running JSF 2.0 to JBoss 7.1.1 running with the built-in JSF libs, it complains about `someMethodInBean` not being a property. Of course it's not a property, it's a method. Who in the world would bind a property to a `valueChangeListener`?

At first I thought, this had something to do with the method being in a superclass of the referenced bean, but that wasn't the case. Adding this particular method to `FooBean` did not make any difference.

So my question is, what did they change so that this breaks now and how can I fix it in a migrating-friendly way?

**edit**

The component is declared as such in our `*.taglib.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">

<!-- ... -->
<tag>
    <tag-name>fooComponent</tag-name>       
    <component>
        <component-type>myProject.FooComponent</component-type>                     
    </component>        
</tag>
```

... which leads to this declaration in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<component>
    <component-type>myProject.FooComponent</component-type>
    <component-class>com.myproject.somemore.UIFooComponent</component-class>
</component>
```

... which leads to the class `UIFooComponent extends UIInput`.

**edit 2**

Now the `taglib` xml looks like this:

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd">

<tag>
    <tag-name>fooComponent</tag-name>       
    <component>
        <component-type>myProject.FooComponent</component-type>                     
    </component>
    <attribute>
        <name>valueChangeListener</name>
        <method-signature>void valueChanged(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)</method-signature>  
    </attribute>        
</tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Still, he complains about `fooBean` not having the property `someMethodInBean`.

*edit 3*

The stack trace is:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /abc/abc.xhtml: The class 'com.myproject.managedbeans.foo.FooBean' does not have the property 'someMethodInBean'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates that the tag attribute isn't been declared as a `<method-signature>` in the component's `<tag>` declaration in the `.taglib.xml` file as follows:

```xml
<attribute>
    <name>valueChangeListener</name>
    <method-signature>void valueChange(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)</method-signature>
</attribute>
```

Make sure that this is properly been declared as above.

---

**Update**: you need to make sure that you've declared the `.taglib.xml` file conform JSF 2.x Facelets XSD (and thus **not** a DTD as it was in legacy Facelets 1.x).

```
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>

    <!-- Tags here -->

</facelet-taglib>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately I could not add this declaration to the taglib.xml, since it's not valid according to the DTD. However adding it did not make any difference. Also, the method signature changes? Not every bean has the same method that responds to a value change of this component.

Comment: DTD? Are you using Facelets 1.x instead of JSF 2.x Facelets? You tagged the question `[jsf-2.0]` so I assumed that you're using JSF 2.x Facelets.

Comment: That could be the problem. See my edit above. That's my current DTD. Should I skip this part and replace the parameter-less `facelet-config` with the one in that answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561299/397898)?

Comment: See answer update. It's `facelet-taglib`, not `facelet-config`.

Comment: Yes, we migrated from JSF1.2 to 2.0, so there may be some things that got lost on the way - thus the old DTD, I guess. Dodged the DTD definition and used your `facelet-taglib` declaration. Now defining the `attribute` works but the error remains. Does the `<method-signature>` need to be exactly like the method in the parameter? What about dynamically binding a bean method to the `valueChangeListener` tag?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be the exact method name. That it still doesn't work would indicate a problem in EL resolving. Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: That's pretty much it. Last exception in the trace is this `ELException` with the truncated "21 more" lines in the console output. (edit: found the remaining lines above.. see http://pastebin.com/GfCc7CGm )

Comment: OK, I am very sorry. Somehow the taglib declaration in our `web.xml` disappeared in various merging actions. I am sure I added this before. The solution to the problem was just to add the taglib definition. No need to add the `method-signature` or anything. But thank you so much for investigating on this. Will still mark this as answered.